# composer install not working on my git repo

Tags: git, github, composer-php

I have the following repo:

https://github.com/latheesan-k/laravel-xero and my project's [composer.json](https://github.com/latheesan-k/laravel-xero/blob/master/composer.json)

On my PC, I have a folder called `test` and inside it a file called **composer.json** with the following contents:

```
{
    "require": {
        "latheesan-k/laravel-xero": "dev-master"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Now when I change into this directory and run the command **composer install** - I get the following error:

> The requested package latheesan-k/laravel-xero could not be found in
>   any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

[image]

Am I doing this incorrectly? I even tried adding it to the [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/latheesan-k/laravel-xero) site and it doesn't seem to work. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 3):

For forks and tests please don't use packagist. Instead use a VCS repository.

Here is how to use them:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs.
Also private repositories are possible.

For your case use this in your `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/latheesan-k/laravel-xero"
    }
],
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
    "latheesan-k/laravel-xero": "dev-master"
},
```

This won't require the packagist you could remove it.